# Complex integral with Cauchy integral formula (z+1)/(z-1)^n

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm busy with computing the following integral:
$\int_{dB(0,2)} {(\frac{z+1}{z-1})}^ndz$.
I used the Cauchy integral Formula and got:
$\int_{dB(0,2)} {(\frac{z+1}{z-1})}^ndz=\frac{2\pi i}{(n-1)!} f^{n-1}(1)$. 
I'm stuck here, can anyone help me out?

Comment: It's not difficult to differentiate $f(z) = (z+1)^n$, is it?

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{d^m}{dz^m}(z+1)^n=n(n-1)\cdot\ldots\cdot(n-m+1)(z-1)^{n-m}$$

with the above coefficient being zero if $\;m>n\;$ ...

Answer (score 0):

By the Cauchy Integral Formula, we have

$$\frac{2\pi i}{(n-1)!}f^{(n-1)}(1)=\int_{\partial{\overline{N(0,2)}}}\frac{f(z)}{(z-1)^n}\ dz$$

In this case, your analytic function $f(z)$ on $\overline {N(0,2)}$ is

$$f(z) = (z+1)^n$$

Find the (n-1)th derivative of $f$, plug in 1 and you're done.